# Facebook Like box for Groups

Tags: facebook

I had a like box on my website for my facebook group. Suddenly it stopped working. Has Facebook made any changes.

this is the code i'm using

```
<iframe     id="blockrandom"
    name=""
    src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;width=292&amp;connections=10&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true&amp;height=590"
    width="300"
    height="630"
    scrolling="auto"
    frameBorder="0" 
    class="wrappermyfacebook" >
    No Iframes</iframe>
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is the group id.